# Angular - How to create a persistent/permanent "Add to Home screen" button in my web app, just like Google Contribute

Tags: angular

How to create a persistent/permanent "Add to Home screen" button in my web app, just like Google Contribute? (see image below)

Background: It's an Angular v5 app with PWA service worker and manifest.json all setup. On landing in the app, a banner will pop-up inviting users to Add to Home Screen. It's all working good.

So how to have a button in my web app like Google Contribute (see image below)?

[image]

Comment: Can't you just add it in AppComponent HTML?

Answer (score 10):

There is really no standard and no API to do that.
That being said, something can still be done.

As specified here:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

If you app meets certain criteria, Chrome will automatically show a banner to the user.

```
Has a web app manifest file with:
    a short_name (used on the home screen)
    a name (used in the banner)
    a 192x192 png icon (the icon declarations must include a mime type of image/png)
    a start_url that loads
Has a service worker registered on your site.
Is served over HTTPS (a requirement for using service worker).
Meets a site engagement heuristic defined by Chrome (this is regularly being changed).
```

As alternative for iOS, I suggest the following library:

http://cubiq.org/add-to-home-screen (https://github.com/cubiq/add-to-homescreen)

Comment: Literally I have all of these things and google is not automatically showing the banner though

Comment: @AntWo it could be that you accidentally dismissed it at one point, it takes 3 months to come up again.

Answer (score 3):

`position: sticky` ? 
add that button outside of your router so it remains there not depending on the view ? not sure exactly what you mean. if you try to describe it a little bit more I could help more.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by `ng-content`. Let's say we have `CardComponent`,
In card.component.html we can have this:

```
<div class="card">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

In our `ContriobuteComponent`, we have:

```
<card>
  <div class="card-block">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Add to Home Screen</a>
   <h2>{{username | uppercase }}</h2>
  </div>
</card>
```

The content in `div` would be injected to `ng-content`. Similarly,in `ReviewsComponent` you can inject different contents

Answer (score 3):

Add an add to home screen button in your app.component.html .
Use styling to position it according to your need.

for example, if you have a

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

change it to

```
       <button class = "add-to-home-screen" 
             (click) = "addToHomeScreenClicked()"> add to home screen</button>
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Answer (score 3):

Personnaly I would add it to app component or create a component outside of the router and I will display it in a fixed div block. Do you need help on the angular aspect or html/css ? For angular in app component

```
<app-fixedFav [inputFav]="favList"></app-fixedNav>
<app-guide (addToFav)="updateFavList($event)"></app-guide>
```

Then in your guide, when someone add a place to favorite emit a favorite list with an EventEmitter, and run an update function in your app component. Then in your fixed nav create an input like in my example or a ViewChild in app component to update your fixed content.